# What is the correct action for questions containing code screenshot?

Tags: discussion, formatting

I was wondering what is the recommended way to deal with questions made of code screenshots? For instance [this one](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/60326/64377) or [that one](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/60339/64377)

I assume that this is a bad idea from the perspective of SE text search ability (let alone the need for the reader to zoom in and the questionable aesthetic look).

- Only ask OP to edit the question?
- Vote down, vote to close?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code as an image is just bad.  It [breaks the site in many ways](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7311767).

You offered three possible options as a response:

1. Ask OP to edit question

   This is certainly an option.  Giving advice on how the site works is usually appreciated.  Although sadly, it is not universally appreciated.
2. Vote Down

   This also a viable option.  Part of the downvote reason states "... it is unclear ...".  I think that code as a picture is unclear, which is why I tend to:
3. Vote to Close

   Code as a picture is hard to interpret on many levels.  Voting to close as *unclear what you are asking* is often warranted in these cases.

Answer (score 3):

What @StephenRauch said is correct in my opinion. However, when I encounter questions with code screenshots I first see if I can edit the question and replace the screenshot with the actual code. If the code is long, then I follow the 1 (ask to edit), 2 (vote down), 3 (vote to close) from the above answer.